# Copy AD user's OU path for new user

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

So I've been creating a new user this way over active directory.  And I want to copy the OU path from the CName variable when the new user is created?  Is there a way I can replicate that OU path for the new user?

```
$Props = (Get-ADUser -identity $CName -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf
    New-ADUser -SamAccountName $SName -UserPrincipalName ($Sname+" "+"@"+$Domain)  -GivenName $Fname -Name ($FName+" "+$LName) -Surname $LName -Email "$Email" -Path "OU=Administrators,OU=Domain,DC=domain,DC=local" -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
```

Comment: Is $CName a distinguishedname ?

Comment: Yes, it's a user input variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a property that shows you the path, but your distinguishedName will contain it. What I'd do is

```
#split on the first comma, save everything after the username to $path    
$path = (Get-AdUser foo).distinguishedName.Split(',',2)[1]
```

Then you can pass that in as the path of the new user object.

Comment: Simple one liner for the Path is great.  Thank's for the illustration.

Comment: What happens when the CN contains "," ?

Answer (score 2):

Your CNs may contain embedded commas (they have to be escaped with '\', but they can be in there), so you may not be able to just split the DN on the commas reliably.  I've always found this to be reliable:

```
$OU = $CName -replace '.+?,((?:DC|OU)=.+)','$1'
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what `$CName` *actually* is but we can see that `Get-ADUser` is, in theory, able to return a userobject from that variable. Let's use that to get the OU from the `DistinguishedName`.

```
$singleUser = Get-ADUser -identity $CName -Properties MemberOf 
$Props = ($singleUser).MemberOf
$OU = ($singleUser).DistinguishedName.split(",",2)[1]
```

`DistinguishedName` already has the OU with the `CN` in front. We split the string on the first comma and return 2 parts. Returning the second element to `$OU` which you can use later.

If `$Cname` is already a `DistinguishedName` then this process can be simplified.

```
$OU = $Cname.split(",",2)[1]
```

Comment: Except that this will fail if CN contains comma

Comment: The thors hammer's answer is applicable